# Does finding something through a map also require a manual search?

Tags: android, lists, maps

I am about to create an android application. The application deals with objects that have location attributes and can be displayed on a map.

I am thinking of having the map be displayed first with nearby objects. By clicking on the object marker on the map, the application will reveal a detailed view.

My question is, do I have to provide another way of search, like manual search? Manual search would require the user to type his location (city+street) manually. Upon that the application would list available objects in a simple list view, not map. Clicking on the list item reveals the detailed view.

What would be the pros & cons of having such a manual search in your opinion?

For me, it would create unnecessary coding hours :) I am asking this question because a design colleague told me this manual stuff is a must have. I dont think so... the application should be intuitive and easy to use. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros:

Your design would be intuitive if it had manual search built in. Here is one very typical use case:

I am searching for things around a location that I will be at later.
I'm not familiar with what the location looks like on a map.
I don't know what part of town it is in, but I know the cross streets.

Cons: more coding hours.

Verdict: Build the manual search.

Comment: as you would zoom and walk around the map, more objects would be loaded to it. So you could search this way for locations you will arrive later.